# Angular X - How to change the path for the compiled JavaScript files in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular6, ng-build

I'm using my Angular App inside an Iframe, and I want to be able to change the path for the javascript files inside index.html after doing a build (ng build).

This is the command I use in order to build my Angular App:

```
npm run env && ng build --aot --prod --environment=prod
```

After doing it, in my dist folder I have this tree:

```
index.html
inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js
main.d83bd9b8af8c676f706b.bundle.js
and etc
```

Looking inside index.html we can see the following:

```
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.5a5809ec73e38d8a32d3.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.7b67fa96a25429619fd6.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.d83bd9b8af8c676f706b.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want to change the build command somehow, maybe there is a flag I didn't saw or any other method to generate index.html with a different path for the javascript files as the following:

```
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathBefore/inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathBefore/polyfills.5a5809ec73e38d8a32d3.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathBefore/scripts.7b67fa96a25429619fd6.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathBefore/main.d83bd9b8af8c676f706b.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: try ng build --prod --base-href=/PathBefore/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to also mention that I tried the --base-href flag and it didn't work :(

Comment: @SGalea This is not what I was looking for, but it stills a workaround that works for me.

Comment: You can use --output-path in the build itself

Comment: might be little late to answer i have same quesion 
following worked fro me
` ng build --prod --deployUrl="PathBefore/" `

Answer (score 3):

set href base in build command

```
ng build --base-href /PathBefore/
```